# Pull and Push Data in .Net, in parallel

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

So far I have only written single core programs. Now I want to improve my performance and trying to find out, how to **pull and push data parallelized**. But I even don't know whether I have the right idea about MultiThreading.

Actually it is a pretty simple case. I pull data from an external interface, rework them so that they are in the right order and push them into an OpenGL Pipeline in order to draw them.

I use a **WPF-application as GUI and render my data with SharpGL(OpenGL wrapped)**. the program runs on a **dual-core processor**.

Here is a sketch of my vision.

[image]

So my idea is to use a bufferArray. Now the clue: How could I write and read in the same array from different thrads?

I was recommended to inform about **OpenMP**. But as it turned out it is not a good idea for .Net and C#.

**Thus could you recommend some fitting papers? Maybe an explanation how to use Task Parallel Library (TPL) for this case.**

Answer (score 1):

The correct description for this is the producer consumer pattern. In .Net you can do this using [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern)

Another implementation can be build using a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview). A basic version:

```
BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>();

async Task Main()
{
    // Fire up two readers
    Task.Run(() => ReadCollection1());
    Task.Run(() => ReadCollection2());

    // Add items to process.
    bc.Add(5);
    bc.Add(6);
    bc.Add(7);
    bc.Add(8);
    bc.Add(9);

    bc.CompleteAdding(); // Signal we are finished adding items (on close of application for example)
}

void ReadCollection1()
{
    foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable()) 
    {
        $"1 processed {item}".Dump();
    }
}


void ReadCollection2()
{
    foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable()) 
    {
        $"2 processed {item}".Dump();
    }
}
```